# When typing in dropdownlist, make Windows search for more than 1 character?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

This may be a bit confusing to explain, but I have a `ComboBox` set to `DropDownList` style. By default, typing while this object has focus searches for an item beginning with whatever the user typed. For example, in a `ComboBox` with 1, 2, and 3, typing 1 will select 1. If you have a `ComboBox` with a1, a2, a3 however, typing a1 will not be combined into one string, but rather search for a and then search for 1. I would like to know how to change this behavior in the cleanest fashion.

What I'm trying to do is have a `ComboBox` with fractions such as 1/8, 1/16, and so on, be accessed by simply typing "1/8". However, this search function only takes 1 character at a time.

Comment: Can you post the code behind of the method that performs the search? That will make it easier to suggest a solution.

Comment: I don't know the code. It's default winform behavior.

Comment: Did you try `AutoComplete` property to achieve search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need suggestion, you can use this code block:

```
    var peopleAutoComplete =
                            context.People
                            .Select(c => new { c.Firstname, c.Surname })
                            .ToArray();
   List<string> peopleAutoCompleteString = new List<string>();
   foreach (var item in peopleAutoComplete)
   {
         peopleAutoCompleteString.Add(item.Surname + " " + item.Firstname);
   }
   AutoCompleteStringCollection collectionSource = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
   collectionSource.AddRange(peopleAutoCompleteString.ToArray());
   txtbx_Surname.AutoCompleteCustomSource = collectionSource;
```

My sample code, add auto complete feature to 'TextBox'.